# SHA1 hash differences between node.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, base64, sha1

I would like to convert this part of node.js code to PHP code. **(WORKING)**

```
function generateHashedPass (password, salt) {
    var byteSalt = new Buffer(salt, 'base64');
    var bytePass = new Buffer(password, 'ucs2');
    var byteResult = Buffer.concat([byteSalt, bytePass]);
    return sha1.update(byteResult).digest('base64');
}

console.log(generateHashedPass('111111', 'UY68RQZT14QPgSsfaw/F+w==') === 'L0xc787MxCwJJaZjFX6MqxkVcFE=' ? "Algo correct" : "Algo wrong" );
```

For now i have something like this in php : **(NOT WORKING)**

```
public function getHashedPass($pass, $salt) {
    $base_salt = unpack('H*', base64_decode($salt));     
    $base_pass = unpack('H*', mb_convert_encoding($pass, 'UCS-2', 'auto'));
    $base_result = $base_salt[1] . $base_pass[1];
    return base64_encode(sha1($base_result));
}
```

But the result is not the same as the node.js function.

**The result should be this :** L0xc787MxCwJJaZjFX6MqxkVcFE=

**When password is :** 111111

**And salt is :** UY68RQZT14QPgSsfaw/F+w==

Comment: Why not take it step by step... When using the same password and slat: Does byteSalt == $base_salt? Does bytePass == $base_pass? Does byteResult == $base_result? If those are all correct, then the problem is in the sha1 or base64 encode functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//----------------------------------------------------
function getCharHex($aString) {

    $bytes  = str_split($aString, 2);
    $result = "";

    foreach ($bytes as $byte) {
        $result .=  chr(hexdec($byte));
    }

    return $result;
}


//----------------------------------------------------
function getHashedPass($pass, $salt) {

    $base_salt   = unpack('H*', base64_decode($salt)); 
    $base_pass   = unpack('H*', mb_convert_encoding($pass, 'UCS-2LE', 'auto'));
    $base_result = getCharHex($base_salt[1].$base_pass[1]);

    return base64_encode(sha1($base_result, true));
}


echo getHashedPass('111111', 'UY68RQZT14QPgSsfaw/F+w==');
//L0xc787MxCwJJaZjFX6MqxkVcFE=
```